# Setting multiple values from a for loop, using an array in app script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to make my code more compact. What I have now works, but it's slow and I don't think it's a best practice. I have a set of array data from Google Sheets, and I want to update a set of page_break values on Google form. I've managed to use a for loop to list all of the page_break ID's, and now I'd like to update them using my array data from Google sheets. I've managed to do this using if statements that filter each page_break ID based on it's title. However, is there a way to make this more slick? Is there a way to turn my page_break ID's into an array and update one with the other?

Thanks for your help. My current code is below.

```
//Trigger
function updateregentspark() {
var fApp = FormApp;
var formId = fApp.openById('1l5OQflzO3R5nW0ZPTHSGqcog47ADLfcnm7m2_82WokU').getId();
var form = fApp.openById('1l5OQflzO3R5nW0ZPTHSGqcog47ADLfcnm7m2_82WokU'); 
var formItems = form.getItems();

//Get Spreadsheet Location Tasks
var sApp = SpreadsheetApp;
var spreadsheet = sApp.openById('1iGWSUhaGxGtsxwOUZpcJBD-kXwubcenN0Q0H6lKAyFQ');
var locationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classic Scavenger Hunt Tasks');
var locationTasks = locationSheet.getRange('A2:A41').getValues();
Logger.log(locationTasks);

//Get Form Page Break Sections and Questions
var i, L=0, thisItem, thisItemType, myCheckBoxItem;

L = formItems.length;
for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
thisItem = formItems[i];
thisItemIndex = thisItem.getIndex();
thisItemType = thisItem.getType();
thisItemTitle = thisItem.getTitle();

//Update Page Break Values

if (thisItemIndex>6 && thisItemIndex<16 && thisItemType===fApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
var sectionHeadersID = thisItem.getId();

if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('1.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[0]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('2.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[1]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('3.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[2]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('4.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[3]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('5.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[4]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('6.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[5]);
}
}
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your code is doing and how it could be speed up.

But you can make it a little shorter if you replace these lines:

```
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('1.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[0]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('2.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[1]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('3.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[2]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('4.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[3]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('5.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[4]);
}
if (thisItemTitle.indexOf('6.') > -1) {
  form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[5]);
}
```

with this:

```
for (var j=0; j<6; j++) 
  if (thisItemTitle.indexOf( (j+1) + '.') > -1) 
    form.getItemById(sectionHeadersID).asPageBreakItem().setTitle(locationTasks[j]);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you for your help!!!